# BlackBerry app update approved but not in App World

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I updated my PlayBook app in App World to Version 1.1, but it doesn't show up in App World. Version 1.0 is still there. In the Vendor Portal, it shows Version 1.1 approved, but now Version 1.0 is denied. What's going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does take some time to update download caches and synchronize all databases.
Just wait for a few hours/days and everything will be fine. :)